# Separar cada dos valores por comas en javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando implementar un sistema que cuando el usuario introduzca datos numericos en un textarea, estos se irán separando cada dos valores por una coma. A modo de ejemplo, otra parte del programa consiste que al pulsar un boton se generen numero aleatorios entre -10 y 99 y esto numero los muestre en un textArea. Esto lo consigo bien con este codido:

```
function tipoRadio()
{
var medidas = elementoID("medidas");//capturo elemento

if (this.id === "medidas_manual")//si el elemento tiene este id 
{
    medidas.value = "";//le vacio
    medidas.disabled = "";//le habilito para poder escribir en el

}

if (this.id === "medidas_aleatorio")//si tenemos este id
{
    var aleatorios = generarValoresAleatorios();//obtengo array aleatorios
    var ale = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < aleatorios.length; i++) {
        ale += aleatorios[i] + ", ";//Los voy añadiendo a una variable con 
                                      comas en medio
    }
    medidas.value = ale;//muestro la variable
    medidas.disabled = "false";     
  }
 }

function generarValoresAleatorios()//Funciona que me genera el array 
                                    aleatorios
{
var arrayAleatorios = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    arrayAleatorios.push(aleatoriosEntreMinimoMaximo(-10, 99));
}
return arrayAleatorios;
```

}

[image: resultado obtenido]

Este resultado le quiero conseguir pero el usuario introducirá los datos de forma manual. Solo numero en formato dos digitos 01, 44, 08 o también es válido -9 , -6 para números negativos. El maximo numero de digitos es dos. El usuario no esta obligado a escribir las comas....
Resumimiendo, el usuario introduce:

- 00 ------------ bien
- 80 ------------ bien
- -5 ------------ bien
- 06 ------------ bien
- 6  ------------ mal faltaría otro dígito
- 7- ------------ mal el menos no puede ir detrás solo delante (numero negativo)

No se si me explico.
Voy editando la pregunta según voy puliendo el problema gracias a los comentarios.
Un saludo

Comment: Hola! Por favor podrías mostrarnos lo que llevas hecho respecto a la separación de comas, para poder guiarte? :)

Comment: Hola Carlos, sería interesante saber que has hecho hasta ahora y un ejemplo de los parámetros de entrada y los parámetros de salida que esperarías, un saludo.

Comment: Cada dos valores, palabras? letras? frases? parrafos?

Comment: Pulsa sobre [edit] y añade el código que tienes, será más fácil para todos

Comment: Seguimos esperando que edites tu pregunta y pongas el HTML  y el código que llevas implementado

Comment: Pero en el código que nos muestras, todos los números están separados por coma, no en grupos de a dos. A lo mejor quieres decir que a medida que el usuario escribe, dos números separados por un espacio deben ser reemplazados por numero1+coma+espacio+numero2

Comment: Es lo que quiero conseguir. El usuario introduce dos valores y el sistema insertar una coma automaticamente. Dos valores coma, dos valores coma

Comment: Ok pero quieres los valores en el formato `1, 5, 34, 48, 7, 29` o en parejas en el formato `1 5, 34 48, 7 29`?

Comment: Formato 1, 20, 25, 8  perdona si no me explico bien

Comment: ¿Y cómo sabes que es `1, 20, 25, 8` y no `12, 02, 58`?

Comment: Y si el usuario inserta un numero de 3 digitos? o le obligas a un maximo de dos?

Comment: Voy editando la pregunta que según voy viendo comentarios y analizando mas el problema voy viendo mas detalles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ya todos han aportado su granito de arena al problema, veamos si mi ayuda sirve de algo.

Primero, defino una función `format` que básicamente analiza el contenido del textarea, lo convierte en un array de valores numéricos y luego llena el textarea con esos valores separados por coma+espacio.

```
var element=document.querySelector('#numeros'),
    contenido=element.value;
    contenido_arr=contenido.replace(/,/g,' ').trim().split(/\s+/);
    element.value=contenido_arr.join(', ');
```

Segundo, tengo otra función que se ejecuta cada vez que se ingresa un caracter al textarea. Si no es numérico, ni coma ni espacio, no inserta el caracter.

Si es un espacio, verifica si hay un espacio acumulado, de manera que escribir `número + espacio + número + espacio` el primer espacio marque un flag: "hay un espacio esperando formateo" y el segundo espacio diga: "el flag está marcado, apliquemos formateo". La idea de esto es que puedas escribir `número + espacio + número` sin que ese espacio gatille el formateo impidiéndote escribir el segundo número. Esto tiene otro caso de borde. Si quieres insertar un número en medio de los que ya tienes, la función necesita tolerar que insertes un espacio antes de gatillar el formateo.

Tercero, si el textarea pierde el foco (evento `onblur`) se gatilla el formateo.

La solución no es perfecta, pero cumple aproximadamente tu intención:

```js
var spacepending=false;
var format = function() {
  var element=document.querySelector('#numeros'),
      contenido=element.value;
      contenido_arr=contenido.replace(/,/g,' ').trim().split(/\s+/);
      element.value=contenido_arr.join(', ');
};
var checkKey = function(event) {
  
  var keyName = event.key;
  if(keyName===',') {
    //no hago naga
  } else if (keyName === ' ') {
    if(spacepending) { // si ya se insertó un espacio, ejecuto el formateo
      format()
      spacepending=false;
    } else { // si no, almaceno que hay un espacio pendiente
      spacepending=true;
    }
  } else if(isNaN(keyName)) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
  
  
};
```

```css
#numeros {
width: 100%;
height: 100px;
background:#f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="numeros" onkeypress="checkKey(event, this)" onblur="format()" ></textarea>
```

Comment: Faltarían los negativos.

Comment: cierto. Pero ahí la implementación es más compleja y más difícil de entender para el usuario, por ejemplo sólo se acepta el `-` si el caracter precedente no es un número. Por eso no incluí negativos ni decimales.

Answer (score 4):

He creado una función que mas o menos resuelve tu problemas , se podría separar en 3 partes , la principal recoge los datos del evento de presionar tecla y si tiene "," pues lo separa en un array por estas ","

La segunda parte seria un for para  recorrer la cadena y cada 2 valores  poner una "," en medio

La tercera parte ya seria la reorganización de valores y  insertarlos en el campo

```js
$("#target").keypress(function (e) {
//1
        var value = $("#target").val() + String.fromCharCode(e.which);
        var splits = value.split(",");

        if (splits.length > 1) {
            value = splits[splits.length-1];
        }

//2
        var finalValue = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0 && i != 0) {
                finalValue = finalValue + ',';
            }
            finalValue = finalValue + value.charAt(i);
        }
    //3
        if (splits.length > 1) {
            splits.splice(splits.length-1);
            var concat = splits.concat(finalValue);
            finalValue = concat.join()
        }
        $("#target").val(finalValue.substring(0, finalValue.length - 1));
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="target" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

Usando la estrategia *divide y vencerás* divide tu problema en dos partes:

- Imagina que tienes una única entrada (un valor de dos dígitos) y quieres comprobar si es válida. Puedes crear una función que tome esa entrada y la valide, por ejemplo `esValorValido(valor);`
- Usando esta función de manera iterativa, puedes validar todas las entradas, así que lo que te queda es dividir el texto del `textarea` en las entradas:

```js
let valorDelTextArea='55, 06,77,-1,';

let valores=obtenerValores(valorDelTextArea);

function obtenerValores(texto) {
  if (!texto) return []; // ningún valor en una cadena vacía
  
  let valores=texto.split(',');
  
  return valores.map(v=> v? v.trim() : undefined );
  
}


console.log(valores);
```

Y ahora puedes crear un bucle que te diga si cada uno de esos valores es correcto o no.